# inserting image to mysql with php

Tags: php, mysqli

I am working on a form and having **3 input file** field. I created 3 column in table to insert it. Is it correct way to do it???

If not then what is the **best way** to fo such stuff

Comment: You should use the relations part of relational database and create a table "image" where each row hold _one_ image (path, you'd normally just save images directly to the file system). Then link this via join tables up to whatever it is the three images were supposed to be linked to.

Comment: Yes!! This would be better

Answer (score 1):

you can create one column then , upload 3 image direct to your server , then join the name of your image with ',' . so all of your image in 1 column and you can use it easily

Comment: Thanks @mohsen, i just completed :)

Comment: My pleasure :) , Good luck